# Deploying a Github App on Heroku

Tags: heroku, github

I have been trying to deploy from a GitHub repository to Heroku. For pushing my changes to GitHub I am using Mac UI Client for GitHub.

Now in the heroku app setup, I changed at https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/myapp/settings . Here I made changes in option GitHub Rep (Link your app to a GitHub repository to see commit diffs in the activity log.). I added as my github-user/repository-name

Now when i use myappname.heroky.com I am redirected to a default page which says :

> Heroku | Welcome to your new app! Refer to the documentation if you
>   need help deploying.

In the documentation it is all commands which is going over me since i use Github UI tool. 
Any idea if this can be deployed w/o using the commands?

I am asking this particular thing, since last time I used AppHarbor and it simply pulled my github rep w/o any hiccups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding your GitHub repo to the Heroku app settings will not set up automatic deployments. It just allows Heroku to provide commit information in the app logs.

To achieve what you are looking for, you need to set up [continuous deployment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) (or "CD"). The easiest way to do this is with a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (or "CI") solution.

One common CI server is [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), though that will require you to set it up manually. Nowadays, there are several automated CI/CD services you can take advantage of, including [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/), [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/), [Codeship](https://www.codeship.io/), [Snap](https://snap-ci.com/). All of them have options to automatically deploy to Heroku after building your app (which can be trigger by a push to GitHub).

Comment: so it is unlike appharbor which does a CD/CI altogether ?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Yes, Heroku does not handle CI/CD, but plenty of third-party services do, and many have Heroku add-ons as well, like https://addons.heroku.com/codeship.

Comment: git push heroku_shortit $COMMIT_ID:refs/heads/master
    [Report a Problem]0 min 3 sec
    Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,50.19.85.154' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

    Permission denied (publickey).

    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.

Comment: You have to upload your public key to Heroku.
Type this in the command line:
 heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
If you don't have a public key, Heroku will prompt you to add one automatically which works seamlessly. Just use:

heroku keys:add